# What is the proper parsing for SQS receive_message?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I've been troubleshooting this for a few days now and I can't seem to understand where to
address this error. I've tested against the receive_message response syntax based on what is documented in Boto3, SQS documentation and Lambda tests to no avail.

```
{
      "errorMessage": "'Messages'",
      "errorType": "KeyError",
      "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 24, in lambda_handler\n    message = response['Messages'][0]\n"
      ]
 }
```

I took this Python snippet directly from the [Boto3 SDK documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/sqs-example-sending-receiving-msgs.html):

```
import boto3
import os

# Create SQS client
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

QUEUE_URL = os.environ['QUEUE_URL']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Receive message from SQS queue
    response = sqs.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=QUEUE_URL,
        AttributeNames=[
            'SentTimestamp'
        ],
        MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
        MessageAttributeNames=[
            'All'
        ],
        VisibilityTimeout=0,
        WaitTimeSeconds=0
    )
    
    message = response['Messages'][0]
    receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']
    
    # Delete received message from queue
    sqs.delete_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
    )
    print('Received and deleted message: %s' % message)
```

Comment: Are you triggering the AWS Lambda function from SQS, or are you manually running the Lambda function at some interval?

Comment: Yes, I’ve set up an SQS trigger in the configuration of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have configured Amazon SQS to trigger the AWS Lambda function, then **you do not need to call any SQS commands**. Instead, the message(s) are provided in the `event` that is passed to the Lambda function:

```py
for record in event['Records']:
    payload = record['body']
    print(payload)
```

If the Lambda function successfully exits, then the message(s) will be automatically deleted from the queue.

See: [Using Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)

Comment: This makes total sense! Just like a S3 event trigger. I’ll give it shot right now.